# Как подогнать размер рамки под QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlabel

Пытался сделать рамку для `QLabel` таким способом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test")
label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.resize(300, 300)
window.show()

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

как сделать так, что бы была такая рамка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А не такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть, что бы рамка была не растянута под окно, а подогнана под `QLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант номер два:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test", alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch(1)                                                 # !!!
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addStretch(1)                                                 # !!!

        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)                             # +++
        mainlayout.addStretch(1)                                             # !!!
        mainlayout.addLayout(layout)
        mainlayout.addStretch(1)                                             # !!!   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> первый текст вывело в рамке на пол окна, второй текст вывело вообще без рамки

Вариант номер три:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("first", alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("second", alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label1.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)        # + label1, - label

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        # layout.addWidget(<object>, <row>, <column>)

        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)

        layout.addWidget(label, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(label1, 2, 2)

        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)                     # +
        layout.setRowStretch(3, 1)                     # +

        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)                  # +
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)                  # +
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)                  # +
        layout.setColumnStretch(3, 2)                  # +

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня получилось собствсенным методом, только там есть небольшая трудность. по факту можно было добавить строчку ```label.setFixedSize(<width>, <height>)``` и все выходит. минус в том что нужно подгонять под текст размер

Comment: @Lcashe не стоит использовать `setFixedSize` для этих целей.

Comment: во избежании еще одного вопроса на платформе, подскажите как сделать подобным образом только для QGridLayout, поскольку данный метод не поддерживает addStretch

Comment: @Lcashe если вам мои ответы помогают и вы в них узнаете что-то новое, вы также можете отметить их как `Ответ полезен`.  Для `QGridLayout` используйте `QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)` и `QGridLayout::setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch)`. Попробуйте сделать самостоятельно, если не получится напишите, я помогу.

Comment: да, все же я не понимаю как оно работает

Comment: @Lcashe что именно вы не понимаете ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107517/discussion-between-lcashe-and-s-nick).

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста в чате

Comment: ок, скажу здесь.     
layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)     
первый текст вывело в рамке на пол окна, второй текст вывело вообще без рамки

Comment: @Lcashe   я ответил на ваш вопрос. См. обновление в ответе. The END.